# Changing path of docker containers in host system

Tags: docker

It seems docker containers are stored in `/var/lib/docker/containers`. Can I change this? Can I make new containers appear in my home directory?

Do I need to build docker from source or is it an option that I can change when creating the container?

Comment: Easiest google search ever.    Type dockerd --help.  Go.

Comment: perhaps  this post help you https://sanenthusiast.com/change-default-image-container-location-docker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rebuild docker, it's an configurable option of `docker daemon(dockerd)`, what you need to do is configuring it with option `--graph`(`-g` for short) and restart it, and migrate your existing docker data if necessary. An example config is:

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -g /opt/docker/lib
```

And then your container info will be under `/opt/docker/lib/containers`, please refer to [docs of dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#options) for more configuration details.